# Geometry Nodes - How to maintain individual instance index after Mesh Boolean operation?

Tags: materials, node-editor, geometry-nodes, procedural, instances

I am instancing shapes on the points of a mesh, assigning each instance an index, which I then put into the group output to be used in the shader to make each instance a different colour.

I am doing this by capturing the Index (I have tried ID as well) before realising the instances, and this is working fine.

[image]

[image]

The problem comes after I am applying the boolean, which makes sense to me since I am modifying the instances and new geometry is being created, but I would still like to be able to have each instance be one solid colour. Instead, it looks like the new geometry is created with differing Indexes than what I would expect based on the attribute I am capturing. Is there some way to reapply the Index that I have captured? See the images for the output I am getting.

[image]

[image]

Apologies if any of my terminology is incorrect, I am still learning.

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you share your blend file? Would make it much easier to understand and develop the setup. You can use https://blend-exchange.com/ if you want. Thanks.

Comment: Sure @Kuboå, you can find it here: https://blend-exchange.com/b/6AYnqJbo

Comment: Don't have much time atm so I'll have to come back to this later if no one else answers, but from a cursory first look I wondered if capturing the attribute _after_ the boolean operation (as _Mesh Island_ Index rather than normal _Index_) would work for you? https://i.imgur.com/0UPgG7d.png Or do you need to do it before because of some other reason?

Comment: That was it, thank you! No I didn't need it before for any reason, still learning so I had no idea Mesh Island was an option. You rock, thanks for the help!